# Open source IoT framework similar to Azure IoT

Tags: azure, open-source

Are there any open source IoT frameworks/runtimes similar to Azure IoT but without vendor lockin, software that will basically run on bare metal device and pull down and run containerized images from a registry and handle configuration/twin synchronization with the cloud?

I like the Azure client solution but we cannot use Azure as a backend for this project and forking it does not seem feasible.

Basic requirements are:

- Runs on bare metal.
- Runs containerized images from cloud.
- Manages configuration/twin synchronization with cloud.
- Provides some client side messaging interface between containers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Balena.io](https://www.balena.io/) stack is [opensource](https://www.balena.io/open/) and in theory you can stand up you own version.

It will handle all the provisioning/managing of the devices but you'll have to supply your own messaging/storage/digital twin bits ontop.

Answer (score 1):

You could hack together something with certificates, MQTT, kafka and firebase.
But you'll spend a lot of energy making it work and managing it.

I guess it is a risk of not taking off Vs a risk of later vendor lock in !
Have you considered using a vendor locked in version for take off while leaving a way to reprogram later to get away from vendor lock in if needed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the opensource [Blynk](https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server) project.
The server is opensource. Mobile application is closed source, but is building based on the community feedback [(link)](https://community.blynk.cc/t/where-is-the-source-code-for-the-android-blynk-app/552).
My home automation project has been developed around Blynk server and their library.